# Cache-control directives not recognized by DevTools

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, http-headers, browser-cache

I'm running a website on Wordpress and lately I've noticed the following "Critical health issue" on the Site health status Wordpress area: ***Page cache is detected but the server response time is still slow***. Even though I use a shared hosting (and I'm aware of its limitations), I'd like to improve this for better performance.

I use Autoptimize for CSS/JS caching and the WP Super Cache plugin for a more advance approach. However, none of them sets `cache-control`, so I've been meaning to set it up without success, as the Developer tools don't recognize it at all.

According to Wordpress, this issue could be solved by using one or more of the following directives: `cache-control, expires, age, last-modified, etag, x-cache-enabled, x-cache-disabled, x-srcache-store-status, x-srcache-fetch-status`.

**My main goal is to set up cache-control Expires directives that actually work for images, fonts and other files that aren't modified often** and thus improve performance and users' experience on the website.

The first way I tried to set this up on .htaccess I used the following piece of code:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/x-js A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
    ExpiresByType video/asf A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/avi A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/java A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/divx A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/msword A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/json A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/png A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/zip A2419200
</IfModule>
```

It did not work and I considered it could even be caused by the formatting of the seconds. Looking for a new approach, I also tried this solution, [shared on Robin's blog](https://robinroelofsen.com/browser-caching-htaccess-apache), but it's still not working:

```
# BROWSER CACHING USING EXPIRES HEADERS
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
  
    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
  
    # Video
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

    # CSS, JavaScript
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

    # Others
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

# BROWSER CACHING USING CACHE-CONTROL HEADERS
<ifModule mod_headers.c> 
    # One year for image and video files
    <filesMatch ".(flv|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|mp4|mpeg|png|svg|swf|webp)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </filesMatch>

    # One month for JavaScript and PDF files
    <filesMatch ".(js|pdf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </filesMatch>

    # One week for CSS files
    <filesMatch ".(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Here's the current response headers, the expires date is obviously wrong, although I'm not sure where that date comes from. Also, I don't understand why `no-cache` is shown.
[image: HTTP Response headers]

Any tips on how to correctly set this up or insights on where the code is wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What requests are you wanting to cache specifically? What are the HTTP response headers for such a request? (Please update your question with this information.) "Page cache is detected but the server response time is still slow" - where do you see that message? What does "Page cache is detected" mean in this context? (You are not going to improve "server response time" by tweaking client-side caching, if that is what you are implying?)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! My aim is for users' browsers to use cached versions of images, fonts and other files that aren't modified often so that they can load the website faster. I've edited the original post to better explain that the "critical" issue is shown on the "Site health" area of the Wordpress dashboard

Comment: `<IfModule mod_expires.c>` - and if _not_ ...? Everything you wrapped into this will of course get completely ignored, should the mod_expires module not be available in your Apache setup. So remove that "wrapper", and see what happens then - if the module is not available, then trying to use these directives should give you an internal server error.

Comment: We need to see the actual "HTTP response headers for such a request" (as mentioned in my first comment), otherwise how do you know it's not working? The HTTP response headers can also provide clues as to why it's not working. However, I don't see how the the setting of these header(s) has anything to do with the "critical health issue" you are citing in "the Site health status Wordpress area"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies, I've just updated the question with more information, including the current HTTP response headers and how Wordpress considers it a "critical health issue"